# MYSQL Sum of subquery

Tags: mysql

I am really stuck with this mysql query. 
I am helping a friend with the creation of a staff/event datatable.
I have successfully created a virtual table seeing the costs of each staff member per event.
In below query I am selecting the event

```
SELECT event.eventid, costs.staffnumber, cost _hour *( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( hours, pause ) ) ) ) /3600 AS costs_event
FROM costs, event
WHERE costs.staffnumber = event.staffnumber
GROUP BY event.eventid, event.staffnumber
```

If I take away the `group by event.staffnumber` it does give me a wrong value. 
Because the different rows have different values but it just assumes that every staffmember has the same `cost_hour`.

Sample:

```
1001 (Eventid)
42 (staffnumber)
112,50 (Costs Sum from 15 EUR * 7,5 hours)
```

second row

```
1001
41 (staffnumber)
78 (Costs Sum from 12 * 6,5 hours)
```

so I want to get 190,50

When I take away the `group by event.staffnumber` I get 210 EUR (14hours * 15 EUR).

So how can I sum up now the `costs_event` column and group them by the `event.eventid`.

Would be grateful for any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Include the cost_hour *inside* the sum:

```
SELECT event.eventid, 
       costs.staffnumber, 
       SUM( cost _hour*TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hours, pause)) ) /3600 AS costs_event
FROM costs
JOIN event
  ON costs.staffnumber = event.staffnumber
GROUP BY event.eventid
```